# How do I define and statically initialize a vector index by an enumeration?

Tags: vector, ada, enumeration

I'm unable to define a vector using an enumeration as an index.

First I define my record:

```
type contact_name is record
    first    : unbounded_string;
    last     : unbounded_string;
end record;
```

I define my enumeration:

```
type profession is (plumber, doctor, lawyer, ombudsman, dealer);
```

I declare my vector of *contact_name* using professional as the index type:

```
package Pro_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Index_Type => Profession, Element_Type => contact_name);
```

Finally, I build my table:

```
Pro_Table : Pro_Vector.Vector := (plumber, ("Bob","daPlumah")) & 
(doctor, "Felix", "FeelGood"))
```

When I try to compile it says expect signed integer type of **Index_Type**. It also claims **Pro_Vector** is undefined. I substituted **profession** for **natural** and it compiled, but my static initialization has errors.

Why won't it accept my enum as an index. I was under the impression that Ada is super safe. By using an unconstrained type like **Natural**, doesn't it compromise safety. Also, how do I statically initialize my vector?

Comment: The generic formal for the index is `type Index_Type is range <>;`, so only a signed integer type matches. If you want a variable-sized sequence type with an enumeration type as the index, you can create one yourself. But I suspect you want a map.

Comment: I tried the Map, but it ended in disaster because of all the much ceremony.  My container will always be the same size as my enumeration.

Comment: It you want one contact_name for one profession you can simply use an array.

Comment: I am trying to learn how to use vectors to see how it compares to plain old arrays.

Comment: When the compiler claims that `Pro_Vector` is undefined I guess it is because the instantiation of the vector package was abandoned.

Comment: If you want containers of a fixed size, keyed (or indexed) by an enumeration, use a plan old array type, they are ideal for that. The Vector containers are meant for variable-sized sequences where typically the meaning of an index is just the sequential position number, and it makes sense to do things like inserting a new element in the middle of the sequence, with the indices of later elements incremented. Yes, Ada is quite safe, and one aspect of that safety is that the compiler rejected your attempt to use Vectors with an enumeration index.

Comment: Fair enough, but it accepts an integer which makes less sense.

Comment: Typical instances of `Vectors` use a subtype of `Integer` as the index; think of the map ceremony as a technical _investment_, rather than a _debt_. Are you perhaps looking to map `Profession -> Vector of Contact_Name` or `Contact_Name -> Profession`?

Comment: @ATL_DEV: Please can you explain why you think that using Vectors with an integer index "makes less sense"? And "less sense" than what?

Comment: Well, does it make sense to have a negative index?  Perhaps, but I can't think of any. You raised an interesting question. Shouldn't Ada also provide additional type attributes such as "counting", "ordinal", "cardinal", "nominal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend a type from the existing vector package and add an indexing function for your enumeration type to get the effect you want.  For vectors they use the Reference and Constant_Reference functions for indexing, so you can do an overload of those functions on your new type and it should use those to index your new vector type.  For any other operations you want to use with an index value, you'll need to overload those too.

You'll also need to either add code to handle when you have more elements than enumeration values or perhaps consider using an bounded_vectors type so the size is maximized at the number of enumerations you have.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors; use Ada.Containers;

procedure Main is

    type profession is (plumber, doctor, lawyer, ombudsman, dealer);
    
    type contact_name is record
        first    : unbounded_string;
        last     : unbounded_string;
    end record;
    
    -- Note the use of Natural here.  That'll correspond
    -- to the Pos values used in the package later
    package Pro_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors 
        (Index_Type   => Natural, 
         Element_Type => contact_name);
         
    -- This package is where the magic happens
    package Vectors is 
        type Vector is new Pro_Vector.Vector with null record;
        function Reference
            (Self  : aliased in out Vector;
             Index : Profession) return Pro_Vector.Reference_Type;
             
    private
        -- Uses Pos to get the "position info" of the enumeration
        -- value
        function Reference
            (Self  : aliased in out Vector;
             Index : Profession) return Pro_Vector.Reference_Type
        is (Self.Reference(Profession'Pos(Index)));
    end Vectors;
    
    v : Vectors.Vector;

begin
    -- Add an item
    v.Append
        (New_Item => 
            Contact_Name'
                (First => To_Unbounded_String("Frank"),
                 Last  => To_Unbounded_String("Dude")));
    
    -- Now you can index it via the profession
    v(Plumber) := 
        (First => To_Unbounded_String("Joe"),
         Last  => To_Unbounded_String("Man"));
    
    
end Main;
```

This is a bounded vector example:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
with Ada.Containers.Bounded_Vectors; use Ada.Containers;

procedure Main is

    type profession is (plumber, doctor, lawyer, ombudsman, dealer);
    Profession_Count : constant 
        := Profession'Pos(Profession'Last)-Profession'Pos(Profession'First)+1;
    
    type contact_name is record
        first    : unbounded_string;
        last     : unbounded_string;
    end record;
    
    -- Note the use of Natural here.  That'll correspond
    -- to the Pos values used in the package later
    package Pro_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Bounded_Vectors 
        (Index_Type   => Natural, 
         Element_Type => contact_name);
         
    -- This package is where the magic happens
    package Vectors is 
        type Vector is new Pro_Vector.Vector(Profession_Count) with null record;
        function Reference
            (Self  : aliased in out Vector;
             Index : Profession) return Pro_Vector.Reference_Type;
             
    private
        -- Uses Pos to get the "position info" of the enumeration
        -- value
        function Reference
            (Self  : aliased in out Vector;
             Index : Profession) return Pro_Vector.Reference_Type
        is (Self.Reference(Profession'Pos(Index)));
    end Vectors;
    
    v : Vectors.Vector;

begin

    Put_Line(v.Capacity'Image);

    -- Add an item
    v.Append
        (New_Item => 
            Contact_Name'
                (First => To_Unbounded_String("Frank"),
                 Last  => To_Unbounded_String("Dude")));
    
    -- Now you can index it via the profession
    v(Plumber) := 
        (First => To_Unbounded_String("Joe"),
         Last  => To_Unbounded_String("Man"));
    
    
end Main;
```